# How can I convert an address link into a button that changes the page when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this address link:

```
<a href="/User/Account/Register">Register</a>
```

Now I would like to use a button for this. How can I convert this to make the page location change if I click down on the button ?

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="location.href='http://www.somepage.com';">` ?

Comment: Thanks but all my CSS is set up for <button> and this is and <input>. Can it be done with a button ?

Comment: `<button onclick="location.href='http://www.somepage.com'">Redirect</button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="windows.location.href='http://xyz.com';>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<a href="/User/Account/Register">Register</a>
```

with:

```
<button onclick="location.href='/User/Account/Register'">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for the same

see this demo [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/k8h5m/2/)